# Eclipse Maven Debug on Server problem

Tags: maven-2, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, web-applications

I created a maven web-app project and then load it up into SpringSource Tool Suite 2.7.1 (which has m2eclipse core and extra installed).

When I do "Run on Server", the extra build steps in the pom.xml are not executed, and I ended up deploying a basic web-app (index.jsp along with WEBINF folder)

I have to build (Maven package) and deploy it manually (copy and paste into Tomcat) so I got the whole lot.

Is there anyway I can instruct m2eclipse/STS to process my pom.xml before "Run on Server" ?

Edit

I have maven-war-plugin, which unzips some zip files etc, this doesn't get executed when I choose "Run on Server"

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891859/deploying-project-created-with-eclipse-and-maven-to-tomcat. Can you find the answer there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
[Eclipse + Maven + Tomcat: testing web apps when the WAR is built with custom options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471386/eclipse-maven-tomcat-testing-web-apps-when-the-war-is-built-with-custom-opti)

Essentially I can use "Deployment Assembly" to deploy things

Answer (score 0):

Which steps in particular are not getting executed?

The first check that I would suggest is to see if the project is [correctly configured](http://www.devx.com/java/Article/36785/1954).

You must ensure that the `executions` are correctly defined to be run on the desired `phases`.

Comment: i've got a plugin, maven-war-plugin, which unzips some zip files etc, this doesn't get executed when I choose "Run on Server"